# How to set button as default on click?

Tags: c, winapi

This is an example of two buttons from the Font dialog in Windows:

[image]

The OK button is the default button, if I click on the Cancel button (mouse down), then the Cancel button will become the default.

How can I achieve this in WinAPI, should I handle the mouse down event of each button, and add to the button that was clicked the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style and remove this style from the other buttons?

Comment: This is a feature of the dialog manager. If you don't want to use a dialog, you can use `IsDialogMessage` and manage the default ID with the DEFID messages noted below.

Answer (score 7):

Send [`DM_SETDEFID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645413(v=vs.85).aspx) to the Dialog Box to change the default button ID. Take note of the following though:

> Using the DM_SETDEFID message can result in more than one button
>   appearing to have the default push button state. When the system
>   brings up a dialog, it draws the first push button in the dialog
>   template with the default state border. Sending a DM_SETDEFID message
>   to change the default button will not always remove the default state
>   border from the first push button. In these cases, the application
>   should send a BM_SETSTYLE message to change the first push button
>   border style

So as well as sending `DM_SETDEFID` to set the new default button, you should send [`BM_SETSTYLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761824(v=vs.85).aspx) to the **old** default button to clear the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I am not using Resources.

Comment: @joseph_m What do you mean? You don't have a real dialog?

Comment: I am using `CreateWindowEx()` to create all Windows.

Comment: Ok well in that case you have to to do it yourself using `BM_SETSTYLE`, and you'll be responsible for handling the return key press and executing the default action. And please mention things like that in future to avoid wasting peoples' time.

Comment: Well, in all of my other WinAPI questions I did not mention that I am not using Resources, so I thought that if I am using Resources I should mention it.

Comment: You should mention everything that is relevant to your question to make it easier for the people who are trying to help you to actually help you instead of waste time.

Comment: And don't assume that people have read your previous questions.  Each new questions needs to be self-explanatory. Always include relevant details.