# How can I set a default button in a window created with CreateWindow instead of a dialog resource in Windows?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm working on a Windows application where I need to create a custom window using the `CreateWindow`function. However, I've noticed that when I use a dialog resource, I can set a default button, but I'm not sure how to do it when I create the window dynamically with `CreateWindow`.

Is there a way to set a default button in a window created with CreateWindow without relying on a dialog resource? If so, what is the best way to achieve this? I'd like to make sure the default button is highlighted and can be activated by the "Enter" key when the window is in focus.

I've been conducting extensive research online, but I haven't been able to find any definitive information on how to handle this particular scenario. Below is an excerpt from my `main.cpp` code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#define IDC_BUTTON1 1001
#define IDC_BUTTON2 1002

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEXA wcex = { };

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIconA(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursorA(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wcex.lpszClassName = "MainWindowClass";

    RegisterClassExA(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExA(0, "MainWindowClass", "", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 416, 228, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_NORMAL);

    MSG msg = { };

    while (GetMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessageA(hWnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageA(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HFONT hFont = CreateFontA(13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "MS Shell Dlg 2");

            HWND hWndEdit1 = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_EDIT, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 100, 20, 200, 21, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            HWND hWndEdit2 = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_EDIT, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 100, 60, 200, 21, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            HWND hWndButton1 = CreateWindowExA(0, WC_BUTTON, "Button 1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 122, 120, 75, 23, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1, NULL, NULL);
            HWND hWndButton2 = CreateWindowExA(0, WC_BUTTON, "Button 2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 203, 120, 75, 23, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON2, NULL, NULL);

            SendMessageA(hWndEdit1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)FALSE);
            SendMessageA(hWndEdit2, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)FALSE);
            SendMessageA(hWndButton1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)FALSE);
            SendMessageA(hWndButton2, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)FALSE);

            SendMessageA(hWndEdit1, EM_SETMARGINS, (WPARAM)EC_LEFTMARGIN, (LPARAM)0);
            SendMessageA(hWndEdit2, EM_SETMARGINS, (WPARAM)EC_LEFTMARGIN, (LPARAM)0);

            SendMessageA(hWnd, DM_SETDEFID, (WPARAM)IDC_BUTTON1, (LPARAM)0);

            SetFocus(hWndEdit1); // Need focus edit control, no default button
        } break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDOK:
                {
                    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "OK", "Title", MB_OK);
                } break;

                case IDCANCEL:
                {
                    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "Cancel", "Title", MB_OK);
                } break;

                case IDC_BUTTON1:
                {
                    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "BUTTON 1", "Title", MB_OK);
                } break;

                case IDC_BUTTON2:
                {
                    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "BUTTON 2", "Title", MB_OK);
                } break;
            }
        } break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I attempted to use `DM_SETDEFID`, but I couldn't find a way to make it work as expected. It seems like I may need to manually handle the `DM_SETDEFID` and `DM_GETDEFID` events, but I'm uncertain about how to go about this in order to ensure proper functionality.

I am looking for guidance on how to effectively manage the `DM_SETDEFID` and `DM_GETDEFID` events or any other recommended techniques that would enable me to set a default button for a custom window created with CreateWindow in a Windows application.

Comment: You need `DefDlgProc` call instead of `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: @i486 Yes, indeed. If the goal is to corrupt memory. The code in question creates a regular window that doesn't have extra window memory allocated for a dialog procedure to store its `DWLP_MSGRESULT` return value. Calling `DefDlgProc` from a non-dialog window procedure has undefined behavior. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defdlgprocw), too: *"In all cases, the `cbWndExtra` member of `WNDCLASS` for a custom dialog box class **must be set to at least `DLGWINDOWEXTRA`.**"*

Answer (score 1):

Assign the [`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles) window style to the default button:

> Creates a push button that behaves like a BS_PUSHBUTTON style button, but has a distinct appearance. If the button is in a dialog box, the user can select the button by pressing the ENTER key, even when the button does not have the input focus. This style is useful for enabling the user to quickly select the most likely (default) option.

Also, make sure your default button has the initial input focus when you window is shown.  And, you may need to send your window a `DM_SETDEFID` message so `IsDialogMessageA()` knows which control ID to send when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, otherwise it will send `IDOK` instead, per MSDN's [Dialog Box Keyboard Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations#dialog-box-keyboard-interface) documentation:

> The system provides a special keyboard interface for dialog boxes that carries out special processing for several keys. The interface generates messages that correspond to certain buttons in the dialog box or changes the input focus from one control to another. Following are the keys used in this interface and their respective actions.
>
> | Key | Action |
> | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... |
> | ENTER | Sends a `WM_COMMAND` message to the dialog box procedure. The `wParam` parameter is set to `IDOK` or control identifier of the default push button. |
> | ... | ... |
>
> The system automatically provides the keyboard interface for all modal dialog boxes. **It does not provide the interface for modeless dialog boxes unless the application calls the `IsDialogMessage` function to filter messages in its main message loop.** This means that the application must pass the message to `IsDialogMessage` immediately after retrieving the message from the message queue. The function processes the messages if it is for the dialog box and returns a nonzero value to indicate that the message has been processed and must not be passed to the `TranslateMessage` or `DispatchMessage` function.

Comment: I gave it a try, and while it provided a visual effect, it didn't meet the functional requirements. When I press the `Enter` key within the text field, it triggers an alert with the `IDOK`, but I need it to trigger `BUTTON 1`. Furthermore, it appears that the style is lost once I change focus using the `Tab` key

Comment: That is perfectly normal behavior introduced by the use of `IsDialogMessage()` in your message loop. See [Dialog Box Keyboard Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations#dialog-box-keyboard-interface) and [return key generates IDOK for button with focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001366/).  You didn't show how you tried to use `DM_SETDEFID`, though. But I don't think you need that.  I've made Win32 GUIs before that have default buttons work correctly without using `DM_SETDEFID`.

Comment: The issues I've encountered with BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON are as follows:

When I press the `TAB` key and the button gains focus for the first time, it loses the characteristic blue border and instead displays a black dashed border. I'm not sure if this is a bug.

Additionally, it seems to lose its distinctive `default button` style when I continue shifting focus between controls using the `TAB` key.

Comment: These problems do not occur in a resource dialog. You mentioned that you had successfully implemented default buttons before. Would it be possible for you to share the code on how you achieved this? I think using the `DM_SETDEFID` and `DM_GETDEFID` messages could be the key to resolving the errors I'm having. I found an answer by Raymond Chen [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822244/how-to-set-button-as-default-on-click) suggesting this approach, but unfortunately, there is no code attached to illustrate the solution.

Comment: Make sure your default button has the initial focus, and if you don't set the window's default ID then simply have your `IDOK` handler invoke your default button's action. But again, I suggest you edit your question to show how you attempted to use `DM_SETDEFID` that didn't work for you

Comment: Update my code, but I'm not sure how to properly handle the `DM_SETDEFID` and `DM_GETDEFID` messages. Also, I need to make sure the focus remains on 'Edit Control 1'. These capabilities can typically be achieved with a resource dialog. My goal is to create a window with the same features and behavior as a resource dialog. Any guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `DM_SETDEFID` is processed by the `DefDlgProc` function only. Replace `DefWindowProc` by `DefDlgProc` in your code.

Comment: I replaced  `DefWindowProc` with `DefDlgProcA` but nothing is displayed

Comment: @CristhianDev I agree with community IInspectable. According to the Doc:[DefDlgProcW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defdlgprocw):In all cases, the `cbWndExtra` member of `WNDCLASS` for a custom dialog box class must be set to at least `DLGWINDOWEXTRA`.